# Xpath query - how ignore content in script tag

Tags: xpath, domdocument

I'm using DomDocument Xpath in PHP to find all images on a page. I read that it's possible to ignore anything that's in a script tag. So in the follow scenario:

```
<body>
<img src="test.png" alt="test">

<script>
<img src="ignore.png" alt="ignore me">
</script>
</body>
```

I run an Xpath query on this, trying to find only the first image and ignore the one in the image tag:

```
<?php
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->query('//img[not(ancestor::script)]');
```

Instead of just getting the image outside of the  tag, I get both images. What could cause this?

Comment: IDK anything about php, but the img is not valid xml. missing end tag.  If I fix that and run your xpath through an xpath tester, works for me.

Comment: It is possible that the HTML parser is "fixing" issues, and moving the `img` outside of the `script` element, which is only supposed to have `text()` child content, not markup. Try selecting the `body` and see what the markup looks like.

Comment: I'm checking external websites, and I'm afraid those won't always have perfect XML, like a missing closing tag. Isn't there a way to make the Xpath query more forgiving?

Comment: How your `$dom` looks like? Did you use something like [loadHTML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)?

Comment: Yes, loaded like this:
<?php
$dom->loadHtml('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $content);
?>

Comment: The example code you provided [appears to work just fine](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/860d461517605fe0c8273777c8d485324ed104a1), with or without passing `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` to `loadHTML()`. Also, prepending `<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>` doesn't make sense for HTML content, but that doesn't influence the result either. Are you sure the code you provided is accurate?